# PHP insert into not inserting and not giving errors, but will insert into when using remote SQL

Tags: php, sql-insert

I'm creating a small project that scrapes specific webshops and gives an alert when the price changed.

When I try to insert a new record (if price is up/down) it won't insert the record. A connection with the database is in place as I check if the last known price went up or down.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `product_prices` (`productId`, `shopId`, `url`, `originalPrice`, `lowestPrice`, `dateChanged`) VALUES ($productId, $shopId, '".$url."', '".$originalPrice."', '".$lowestPrice."', '".$dateChanged."')";
```

When I echo $sql it generates this:

```
INSERT INTO `product_prices` (`productId`, `shopId`, `url`, `originalPrice`, `lowestPrice`, `dateChanged`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'https://www.webshop.com/', '999,99', '800', '2020-07-28 15:04:30')
```

When I use a remote SQL client (like Sequal Pro) and paste the output of above line it will insert the record. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Usually, you can ask the MySQL connector to return errors. Additionally, that code is open for SQL injection

Comment: The problem can be from the quotation marks. Please add the errors to help you solve your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found, I wasn't using `$mysqli->query($sql);` after inserting. Now I will dive into SQL injection. Thanks @nico for the heads-up.